# Fill NaN with same text as entire column using openpyxl?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, null, nan

I am working in a large dataset (excel), and one of the columns has the same value for every entry. However, some of the cells are blank. Is there a way to fill that with the text from the column? I have provided an example dataset here:

[image]

In this example, this is read as a workbook using

openpyxl.load_workbook('states.xlsx')

I want to fill "MA" where it is blank. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

`fillna` is one solution

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'City':['city1','city2','city3'],
    'Zip':[1,2,3],
    'State':[np.NaN,'MA','MA']
})

fill_val = df['State'].dropna().unique()[0]

df['State'] = df['State'].fillna(fill_val)
df
```

Output

```
    City    Zip State
0   city1   1   MA
1   city2   2   MA
2   city3   3   MA
```

Comment: Using `mode` rather than `unique` would be more robust against one weird row.

Comment: why is mode better than unique? Thank you!

Comment: `unique()[0]` is getting a list of the unique values and then taking the first element while `mode` directly finds the most common element. `mode` is better if say 99 rows have `MA` as the State, but one row has `CA`

Comment: is there a way to do this using openpyxl? I am using a for loop and trying to iterate over data, and it is getting thrown off because i am going from openpyxl to pandas

Comment: I don't know anything about openpyxl. I think it might be best if you started a new question

Comment: I edited the above in hopes someone can help - it would be useful to not have to read it into pandas and use openpyxl to accomplish the above from @mitoRibo

Comment: please start a new question with the tag openpyxl https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openpyxl